# $A$ is a finitely gen. $k$-algebra. How to show that the set of closed points of $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is dense without using that $A$ is Jacobson?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra.

I would like to show that the set of closed points of $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is dense, but without using the fact that the nilradical of a finitely generated $k$-algebra is the intersection of all maximal ideals.

---

I know that the closed points of $\operatorname{Spec}A$ are the maximal ideals of $A$.

I also know that if $\frak m$ is a maximal ideal of $A$, then $A/\frak m$ is a finite extension of $k$, by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

**I would like to show that if $f \in A$ and $D(f) \ne \varnothing$, then $D(f)$ contains a maximal ideal of $A$.**

I know that $A_f$ is also a finitely generated $k$-algebra as well.

Comment: So by contradiction the closure of the closed points is supposed not to be dense thus all the closed points are contained in $V(f)$ for some $f\ne 0 \in A$ which implies that $A[f^{-1}]$ has no maximal ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $A\cong k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/I$ as a quotient of a polynomial ring. Then $D(f)$ is the spectrum of $A_f\cong k[x_1,\cdots,x_n,z]/(I,zf-1)$, and by the assumption that $D(f)\neq\emptyset$, we have that $(I,zf-1)$ is a proper ideal of $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n,z]$ and is hence contained in a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. This gives a closed point in $D(f)$.

To see this is also a closed point of $\operatorname{Spec} A$, we use the characterization the closed points in the spectrum of a finitely generated $k$-algebra have residue field a finite extension of $k$. As $(A/I)_f\cong A_f/I_f$, the residue field of the closed point of $D(f)=\operatorname{Spec} A_f$ is the same as the residue field of that same point considered in $\operatorname{Spec} A$, so it is again a closed point of $\operatorname{Spec} A$.

Comment: To check my understanding: i.) since $D(f) \ne \varnothing$, then $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n,z]/(I,zf-1)$ has prime ideals, and all these prime ideals do not contain $f$?

Comment: ii.) If $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n,z]/(I,zf-1)$ has prime ideals, then there exists a maximal ideal, and this ideal does not contain $f$?

Comment: Yes, because $f$ is invertible: any ideal containing a unit is the whole ring.

Comment: Your ideal $m$ is a closed point in $D(f)$, but $D(f)$ is open in spec$(A)$, so this doesn’t necessarily translate back to a closed point in spec$(A)$ which contains $f$. How are you using that the residue fields are finite extensions?

Comment: @JakeZweifler see the edit.